# Difference between Spring Async, Async with CompletableFuture and Java8 parallel stream

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, completable-future, spring-async

I am working on list to validate list data and then map it to Db Entity using MapStruct and finally save list in multiple table as batch process - parent and child table using Spring data JPA. I am using parallel stream to achieve to complete this process. Also I need result of persisted data in response where all final data I am exporting to one file to upload.

***Which one suite best in my case and why?***

```
List<Data> data; //10K records

converting into list of list with 1K records
List<List<Data>> datalist; //1K records in each list

datalist.parrallelStream.foreach( data-> 
{
    validate(data);
    List<Entity> list = mapToEntity(data);
    EntityRepo.saveAll(list); //batch_size = 1000; oracle db
}
) 

class Entity {
@Id
String id; // generating Id manually in my code using UUID. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Async - This will make the processing asynchronous and make it work independently.

Java 8 parallelStream - creates subsequent threads based on the input data and processes it simultaneously.

In your case, the data will be processed by independently in multiple threads.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).